# Use existing python libraries in spyder

Tags: python, path, spyder

I have installed Spyder ide on my Mac machine. I already had python installed on my system and I had installed several libraries using pip install (like pandas, sklearn etc). Now when I try to import them in Spyder, they don't work. From python shell, I imported those libraries and added that path to PYTHONPATH in Spyder. But it is still not working. It seems it is searching in the `/Applications/Spyder.app/Contents/Resources/` folder. But why wouldn't adding the existing python library path work? Can someone tell me what I am missing?

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) You need to connect your other Python with Spyder. Please read [this](http://docs.spyder-ide.org/current/faq.html#using-existing-environment) to learn how to do that.

Comment: @CarlosCordoba I have tried that but doing that gives me this error 'Fatal Python error: initfsencoding: unable to load the file system codec
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x0000000118d2adc0 (most recent call first)'

Comment: Please revert the changes you did to PYTHONPATH and try again.

Comment: @CarlosCordoba Thank you so much, it worked. One small addition. We need to install spyder-kernels if it is not already present in the new python environment.